# Fail to start Minikube on Debian

Tags: minikube

I installed Minikube on my Debian 10, but when I try to start it, I
get these errors:

```
$ minikube start

* minikube v1.25.2 on Debian 10.1
    * Unable to pick a default driver. Here is what was considered, in preference order:
      - docker: Not healthy: "docker version --format {{.Server.Os}}-{{.Server.Version}}" exit status 1: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.40/version: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
      - docker: Suggestion: Add your user to the 'docker' group: 'sudo usermod -aG docker $USER && newgrp docker' <https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/>
      - kvm2: Not healthy: /usr/bin/virsh domcapabilities --virttype kvm failed:
    error: failed to get emulator capabilities
    error: invalid argument: KVM is not supported by '/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64' on this host
    exit status 1
      - kvm2: Suggestion: Follow your Linux distribution instructions for configuring KVM <https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/reference/drivers/kvm2/>
    * Alternatively you could install one of these drivers:
      - podman: Not installed: exec: "podman": executable file not found in $PATH
      - vmware: Not installed: exec: "docker-machine-driver-vmware": executable file not found in $PATH
      - virtualbox: Not installed: unable to find VBoxManage in $PATH
```

I added my user to the docker group using:

```
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

and I insalled kvm without any apparent problems as far as I understand:

```
kvm --version
QEMU emulator version 3.1.0 (Debian 1:3.1+dfsg-8~deb10u1)
Copyright (c) 2003-2018 Fabrice Bellard and the QEMU Project developers

$ lsmod | grep kvm
kvm                   729088  0
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm


$ sudo virsh list --all
 Id   Name          State
-----------------------------
 1    debian10-MK   running
```

What could be the problem and solution then?

Thanks,
Tamar

Comment: To install minikube in your system, did you follow a tutorial? Did you check that the system meets the [requirements](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/) to install minikube?

Comment: yes, I followed this for Minkube: https://www.linuxtechi.com/install-minikube-on-debian-10/ and this for kvm: https://www.linuxtechi.com/install-configure-kvm-debian-10-buster/